# SAS text to date

Tags: sas

I have an excel file and I read it into SAS using proc import. The Date column has a Text value: Mar 2017
How can I convert it to a date corresponding to the last day of the month? i.e.31MAR2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the following code for this

```
data have;
 dt='Mar2017';
 output;
 dt='Apr2017';
 output;
 dt='May2017';
 output;
 dt='Aug2017';
 output;
run;

data want;
 set have;
 newdt=input(dt,MONYY7.); /*Convert text into date, it will point to first day*/
 lastDay=intnx ('month',newdt,0,'E'); /*Find the last day of month*/
 format newdt lastDay date9.;
run;
```